# How do I stop a script from the command line?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How do I stop this script from the command line?
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar`

I can kill this process by using `Ctrl+C` `pkill -9 java` but I want to stop this after 30 seconds automatically. I have to run this script from the server, so whenever this script runs I want to kill it after 30 seconds.

Comment: Why do you want to stop it after 30 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule the pkill tasks and run it every 30 seconds, but this doesnt make a lot of sense.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517501/selenium-2-how-to-check-that-server-is-running-and-stop-the-server) you can also hit a URL (`http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer`) at the end of your test to shutdown the Selenium server. Maybe that gives you some direction.

I think your question does not have enough information to give a better answer though :)